# Magento Static block from new php file

Tags: php, magento

In Magento e-Commerce system, I made new php page to list some products from database and I need to make this list to appear in left or right column at home page. and I don't know how to make that. I tried to put the php file content at new static block content and it doesn't work with me and I'm not familiar yet with Magneto to do that.

Comment: Are you using custom design or is it clean magento installation?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it if you're new to Magento would be:

1. Name your php file for example: `something.phtml`
2. Put your file in:
   `app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/`
3. Log in to `admin` backend.
4. Go to `CMS/pages` and click on `Home page` entry. Change tab to `design`.
5. In `Layout Update XML` locate `<reference name="right">` segment and
   add this to it:

   `<block type="core/template"  name="my_prod_list"
   template="catalog/something.phtml" />`
6. Click `Save page` at top right corner and voila! Your element should
   be visible on main page.

It may be possible that you would have to clear magento cache for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and I will try this solution and please if you have hardest way please tell me cause I need to do it provisionally. Thanks again and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Don't worry, for such small thing like box on main page this is the right way to do it.